# (palantir) (ts) Input the start date (localdate) and number of months (int) from the user, send the values to a function and calculate the end month

Tags: node.js, typescript, palantir-foundry

I've a webhook that takes start date and end date of the forecasting period for the data. The webhook takes two string inputs.

I've created a action form which inputs the start and end date to forecast, and it's working fine.
What I want to do for the form is to input " number of months to forecast for " instead. I'm using a function to process the form input and send it to webhook.

And this is the function I tried using to convert, and its returning an object for some reason :

````
    @Function() 
    public calcendmonth(start_month: LocalDate, forecastmonth:Integer):string{
        var endMonth:string
        var endMont = start_month.plusMonths(forecastmonth);
        endMonth = endMont.toString();
             console.log(endMonth)
        return endMonth;
    }```

// For reference, this is the entire code to process input to webhook : 

    export interface MoodysWebhookInput {
    scenario: string,
    vin: string,
    exterior_color: string,
    interior_color: string,
    mileage_per_year: Integer,
    start_month: string,
    forecast_month: Integer,
    sale_type: string,
    moodys_region: string,
    state: string,
    mileage: Integer,
}

export class MyWebhookFunctions {

    @Function() 
    public calcendmonth(start_month: LocalDate, forecastmonth:Integer):string{
        var endMonth:string
        var endMont = start_month.plusMonths(forecastmonth);
        endMonth = endMont.toString();
             console.log(endMonth)
        return endMonth;
    }
  //@ts-ignore
    @OntologyEditFunction() 
    public CalculateResidual( invoice: Integer, // Calculator for MOODYS Residual Values
     incentive: Integer, 
     costOfSale: Integer,
     addOn: Integer, 
     AddOnPercentageDepr: Integer, 
     months: Integer,
     ):void{
    
    var resval: number;

    var resval = invoice - incentive + costOfSale;
    
    const resvalAdd = resval + (addOn - (addOn * (AddOnPercentageDepr / 100)));
    const data = Objects.create().trainingCalculatorForMoodys(Uuid.random());
   {
      data.residualValue = resval; 
          data.residualValueAddOn = resvalAdd;
            // data.holdingCost = holdcost; 
            //     data.holdingCostAddOn = holdcostAdd; 
  }
  {
    if (months !== 0){
    const holdcos = Math.floor(resval/months);
    const holdcost = holdcos;

    const holdcostAd = Math.floor(resvalAdd / months);
    const holdcostAdd = holdcostAd;
     
    //return [resval, resvalAdd, holdcost, holdcostAdd];

    //console.log(resval); console.log(resvalAdd); console.log(holdcost); console.log(holdcostAdd);

  // const data = Objects.create().trainingCalculatorForMoodys(Uuid.random());
   {
      // data.residualValue = resval; 
      //     data.residualValueAddOn = resvalAdd;
            data.holdingCost = holdcost; 
                data.holdingCostAddOn = holdcostAdd; 
  }
    }
  }

    }



    // @OntologyEditFunction()
    // public createMoodysRequestAndResults(
    //     rawMoodysResponse: string
    // ): void {
    //     const parsedMoodysResponse = JSON.parse(rawMoodysResponse);
    // }

    @Function()
    formatMoodysWebhookInput(
      scenario: string,
      vin: string,
      exteriorColor: string,
      interiorColor: string,
      mileagePerYear: Integer,
      startMonth: LocalDate,
      //endMonth: LocalDate,
      saleType: string,
      moodysRegion: string,
      state: string,
      mileage: Integer,
      forecastmonth: Integer,
    ): MoodysWebhookInput {
        if (
          !scenario ||
          !vin ||
          !exteriorColor ||
          !interiorColor ||
          !mileagePerYear ||
          !startMonth ||
          //!endMonth ||
          !saleType ||
          !moodysRegion ||
          !state ||
          !forecastmonth ||
          !mileage 
        ) {
            throw new UserFacingError("Some required fields are not set.");
        }
        // Create a new object to store the request data.
        const requestData = {
            scenario: scenario,
            vin: vin,
            exterior_color: exteriorColor,
            interior_color: interiorColor,
            mileage_per_year: mileagePerYear,
            start_month: startMonth.toISOString(),
            end_month: this.calcendmonth(startMonth, forecastmonth),
            sale_type: saleType,
            moodys_region: moodysRegion,
            state: state,
            mileage: mileage,
          forecast_month: forecastmonth,
        };
        return requestData;
    } ```
````